# Javascript Does Not Fire Unless I Go To The Inspect Console

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing something strange with my JavaScript code below. The JavaScript is meant to trigger an animation 70px before the user scrolls over the id, but for some reason the only time the code triggers is when I scroll over the area where the animation is supposed to display, and then go to the inspect console in Google Chrome.

**Anybody have any ideas why the code will not fire normally? I have not put any debugging code in place. I am running JQuery and Waypoints with Bootstrap.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('#element-to-animate-left').css('opacity', 0);
 
  $('#element-to-animate-left').waypoint(function() {
      $('#element-to-animate-left').css('opacity', 1);
      $('#element-to-animate-left').addClass('slideInLeft');
  }, { offset: "70" });
 

 
  $('#element-to-animate-right').css('opacity', 0);
 
  $('#element-to-animate-right').waypoint(function() {
      $('#element-to-animate-right').css('opacity', 1);
      $('#element-to-animate-right').addClass('slideInRight');
  }, { offset: "70" });
 
});
```

```css
.strategic-marketing-header {
    margin-top:12rem;
}
.strategic-marketing-paragraph {
    padding:4rem 2rem 5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<section class="section-what-is-strategic-marketing">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-7" id="element-to-animate-left">
                    <h2 class="header-h3 strategic-marketing-header">What Is Strategic Marketing?</h2>
                    <p class="paragraph strategic-marketing-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg" id="element-to-animate-right">
                    <div class="image-box">
                        <img class="centered-image" src="resources/img/index/strategic-marketing.png" alt="Strategic Marketing Graphs">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Probably because opening the console shrinks the pages viewport?

Comment: I thought that too Jonas, but after testing multiple viewports its still not triggering

Comment: Jonas you were right! It was the viewport! So how do i get the animation to trigger 70px before the id?